# What does "жена-собственница" mean?

Tags: значения, выражения

I can't understand the meaning of `жена-собственница`.

У меня жена-собственница! Хорошо ли это?

Answer (score 6):

Жена-собственница is an extremely possessive, jealous wife. Собственник/собственница can describe a wife, husband, girlfriend or boyfriend. Also, it's sometimes used to describe a mother who has become overly possessive of her son.

Answer (score 2):

I was going o say "authoritarian wife" but googling hints that this term has not that subtle sexual connotation that by no means applicable for `жена-собственница`. So it's about a wife who's quite annoying it her attempts to over control, most likely quite jealous. It's not gender biased though, the masculine `собственник` uses as much frequently.

Answer (score 1):

`Жена-собственница` that means `муж подкаблучник`.